# Nvidia driver not loading on Xubuntu 17.04, slow performance with 1050 card

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, 17.04, 3d

I'm running Xubuntu 17.04 on a system with an Nvidia GTX 1050 video card, AMD Phenom II X4 955 Processor, 16GB of RAM and SSD drive. Kinda old CPU, but it's worked fine.  It seems that ever since I upgraded to 17.04 a while back the 3D performance has gotten worse on this machine. Playing games like Minecraft or Nexuiz is unbearably slow and seems to be heavily CPU bound.  I'm running the nvidia proprietary 375 driver as selected in the restricted drivers config. Here is the output of lspci and the glxinfo direct line:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0300]' 
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050] [10de:1c81] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Device [196e:11c0]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_375_drm, nvidia_375

$ glxinfo | grep direct
direct rendering: Yes
    GL_ARB_direct_state_access, GL_ARB_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ARB_draw_indirect, GL_ARB_draw_instanced, GL_ARB_enhanced_layouts, 
    GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect, GL_ARB_occlusion_query2,
```

I also notice that if I start the nvidia settings GUI program, it only shows two categories on the left "Application Profiles" and "nvidia-settings Configuration". Almost like its not loading the nvidia driver.

I have another computer running Xubuntu 16.10 that also has an Nvidia GTX 1050 in it and it runs great and the 3D performance is fast.

What could be wrong?

UPDATE: I've included the WW and EE messages in the Xorg.0.log file as they may give some clues:

```
$ egrep "EE|WW" /var/log/Xorg.0.log
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    10.597] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    10.597] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    10.597] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    10.597] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    10.597] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    10.600] (WW) "glamoregl" will not be loaded unless you've specified it to be loaded elsewhere.
[    10.632] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[    10.632] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
[    10.635] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[    10.635] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
[    10.637] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for (null): -22
[    10.637] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for (null): -22
[    10.637] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for (null): -22
[    10.637] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:01:00.0: -22
[    10.637] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:01:00.0: -22
[    10.637] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    10.637] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[    10.637] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    10.651] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
```

UPDATE: I just tried booting the system to a live USB drive running Xubuntu 17.04 (A different installation). Then I installed the nvidia driver there and it worked and I get full hardware acceleration.  So it would seem that the system in question is misconfigured somehow, but at least I know the card will work with 17.04.  It would be a shame for me to have to reinstall, I wonder if there are other packages that I should try reinstalling first, like the whole xorg system?

Comment: Indeed, the Nvidia X server Settings issue is a symptom of an improperly installed driver. I suggest you purge all the Nvidia drivers (because certainly you've been "experimenting") - `sudo apt purge nvidia* - and install again, preferably an even newer version (you may need to add a PPA for that). Regarding your Xubuntu, 16.10 is EoL, please use a supported release at all times.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Actually I haven't experimented a lot on this machine. But I tried your suggestion. I purged all the nvidia related packages and then just selected the nvidia driver from the GUI and rebooted. Same issues persist.

Comment: Is it the same driver version you nused on Xubuntu?

Comment: It's all Xubuntu. I haven't changed OSes.  Yes the driver version was the same (nvidia 375) in both cases. It doesn't let me choose another version of the nvidia driver via the GUI.  The other computer running 16.10 is also using the nvidia-375 driver, which I find interesting since it kinda points to an X config or library issue instead of the nvidia drivers.  One difference is that on the machine that works I have a xorg.conf because I'm doing multi screen and needed some options and the other one doesn't.

Comment: Available drivers versions depends on the release and yes, 375 is the latest available at the standard Ubuntu repos. You may try newer ones by adding a PPA: https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: I tried this and tried each of the different available drivers and none of them work. Added some output from Xorg.0.log file that may be helpful.

Comment: Since your nvidia module is missing, what does the /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-375/375.66/4.4.0-92-generic/x86_64/log/make.log say about any errors in building the module?

Comment: Good idea, but from what I can tell the module is built without any errors in the make.log and 4 .ko files show up in the module directory.  lsmod | grep nvidia shows the nvidia kernel module is loaded and in use. The X log is probably complaining about the X nvidia module though right?

Comment: @DavidFoerster  Thanks for the suggestion. I've adjusted my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my particular case reinstalling Xubuntu 17.04 from scratch fixed the problem.  So it would appear that some package or configuration other than the nvidia packages and configuration files became corrupted. On the bright side, I'm happy the solution wasn't "That card doesn't work with 17.04 or something that requires waiting for an updated driver."

Answer (score 0):

use Search to find "Additional Drivers"

in additional drivers tab, several NVIDIA binary options will be presented, along with an X.Org X Server.   mine had the X.Org selected.  i changed it to the NVIDIA version 381 binary (384 is more recent, i'll probably change it to that later)

anyhow, it took a good couple minutes to apply, then i restarted, and sure enough in the Search now appears the NVIDIA X Server application, all my games are smoking the FPS

lol :)

Comment: let me just mention this was driving me nuts, and of course after i try all the hard things, the easy thing was the answer ;)

Comment: You don't need to comment on your own answer. You can simply `edit ` it.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work for me and I had already tried it. I tried it again just to be sure.